# White line appears on image when image is converted to data using jpegData?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

[image]

When I convert UIImage to data using jpegData compression it will add a thin line on top of the image, why is that so?
Also I'm using this func for resizing image.
After resizing Im converting to jpegData.

```
    func resizeImage(image: UIImage, targetSize: CGSize , percentage:Double) -> UIImage {
        let size = image.size
        
        let widthRatio  = targetSize.width  / size.width
        let heightRatio = targetSize.height / size.height
        
        // Figure out what our orientation is, and use that to form the rectangle
        var newSize: CGSize
        if(widthRatio > heightRatio) {
            newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * heightRatio, height: size.height * heightRatio)
        } else {
            newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * widthRatio,  height: size.height * widthRatio)
        }
        
        // This is the rect that we've calculated out and this is what is actually used below
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)
        
        // Actually do the resizing to the rect using the ImageContext stuff
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, percentage)
        // UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize , false , )
        image.draw(in: rect)
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        
        return newImage
    }
let image = resizeImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.60)!
```

Comment: My guess is your calculation of the frame size is not precise, it's slightly off, which causes the few lines of "nothing". Did you try with very simple image, say 100x100px? does it happen to such image as well?

Comment: I agree.  Make sure `newSize` is a whole number of pixels (so its components are like 120.0 instead of 120.34)

Comment: After resizing image , image is fine . But when i convert to jpegData , then line appears.